# Subversion Jenkins plugin : which svn binaries are used and where are they located?

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Currently, I have Jenkins v1.559 installed. The Subversion plugin (v2.4.5) allows to specify in Jenkins configuration which version of SVN from 1.4 to 1.7 should be used to checkout projects.

On the machine that runs Jenkins (CentOS), the version of Subversion installed is 1.8.

In a Jenkins job, I need to perform svn operations using Shell scripts. But performing such operations using Subversion 1.8 on a project checkouted with 1.7 throws errors (the .svn files structure is not compatible between 1.7 and 1.8).

My question is : which Subversion binary does the Subversion Jenkins plugin use ? All the Subversion bins from 1.4 to 1.7 are they embedded within the Jenkins plugins ? If that so, where are they located ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version (2.5.x) of the Plugin supports Subversion 1.8:
[Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin)

But regarding your question, as far as I know they are using the SVNKit library, so the functionality of 1.4 to 1.8 are embedded, but you will not find binaries here.

Comment: I know he latest version of the plugin supports SVN 1.8. But the version of Jenkins installed does not support this version of the plugin (Subversion plugin requires core version 1.568) and I can't upgrade Jenkins right now. Thx for the reply about the svnkit library. So, no binary. I guess I will have to install an older version of the Subversion client...